# Is composer.phar required after installation?

Tags: composer-php

This may be a stupid question but after a fair bit of googling i and still unsure weather i should be removing the the composer.phar file after installation. Is the files just part of the installation or required to run the application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Composer executable is used to manage your dependencies, which is mostly "update" and "install". The result is an autogenerated autoloader and a complete tree of files from the required packages of the application.

The executable itself is not part of the application and therefore is not needed to run it. For security reasons it should not be present on the live servers unless you really know it has to be there, because it seems like a good idea to not give an attacker some useful tools into their hands.

The proper places to have the executable are your development environment (in order to add new packages and update the old ones) and the deployment server that puts the application onto the live server (otherwise you cannot install the packages that your application runs with).

I know that people tend to create a workflow that simply pushes a branch to production, and a post-transmit hook then runs `composer install`, but this is dangerous from a reliability standpoint: What if Github has an unexpected downtime and you push to production, unable to download the new packages? In this scenario, the server doing the deployment actually is the production server and so requires a copy of the Composer executable, but I explained that this is no ideal setup.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation. Admittedly i am new to both composer. After installing composer using apt-get, i discovered the composer.phar file in my /home/user directory and i was unsure why it (or how) it made it's way there. 

EDIT: if i understood you correctly the composer.phar file should be in the root of every project, in my case my laravel projects?

Comment: No, the `composer.phar` should be in a convenient place once, that is inside your `$PATH`, so that you can easily call `composer` everywhere without having to explicitly specify the path to it. It is also a good idea to rename or symlink it to have the file name without the `.phar` extension. It isn't technically needed on the command line (at least on Linux), and is more convenient. You can also create a shell alias definition to call Composer. But you really only need one copy of the `phar` file on a machine.

Comment: AH! Now things are making more sense, laravel request you add this line to your $path variable `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin`. I did not have a clue at the time what it was referring to but i am guessing that $HOME is in reference to the home directory where the file is located.

Comment: `$HOME` is the home directory of the logged in user on the shell, and the path Laravel is adding is pointing to the installation directory of Composer for globally installed tools. That `.composer` directory is where Composer stores the global configuration and it's cache. However you usually do not have `composer.phar` there, but you can put it there as well. There is a chapter with more details: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx